# How can I get distribution function from characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Suppose $F=F(x)$ is distribution function of r.v. $X$ and its characteristic function is $\varphi_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx}dF(x)$. Then for any $a<b$ where $F$ is continuous at $a,b$ we have
$$F(b)-F(a)=\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-c}^c\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\varphi_X(t)\;{\rm d}t$$
I wonder if we can get the distribution function $F(x)=\mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$ directly by taking $a\to-\infty$ of the equation above, say
$$F(x)=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-c}^c\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itx}}{it}\varphi_X(t)\;{\rm d}t$$
If not, how can I calculate $F(x)$ from its characteristic function $\varphi$?

Well, actually I read a textbook which says
$$F(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\lim_{\sigma\to0^+}\int_{(-\infty,x]}{\rm d}y\int_{\mathbb R} {\rm e}^{-ity-\sigma^2t^2/2}\varphi_X(t)\;{\rm d}t$$
but I have no clue why there is a term $e^{-\sigma^2t^/2}$.

Comment: see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/104491)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can find $F(x)$ by taking limit as $a \to -\infty$ (through continuity poinst of $F$).

$\int_{\mathbb R} {\rm e}^{-ity-\sigma^2t^2/2}\varphi_X(t)\;{\rm d}t$ is the density function of $X+Y_{\sigma}$ where $Y_{\sigma} \sim N(0,\sigma)$, $X$ and $Y_{\sigma}$ being independent. This follows from the fact that $e^{-\sigma^2t^2/2}\varphi_X(t)\;{\rm d}t$ is the characteristic function of $X+Y_{\sigma}$  and the Proposition below.  Henec $\int_{(-\infty,x]}{\rm d}y\int_{\mathbb R} {\rm e}^{-ity-\sigma^2t^2/2}\varphi_X(t)\;{\rm d}t$ is the distribution function of $X+Y_{\sigma}$ which tends to the distribution function of $X$.

Proposition

If the characteristic function $\phi_Z$ of $Z$  is integrable then $Z$ has  a density given by $f_Z(t)=\int e^{-ity} \phi_Z(t) dt$.

[This proposition  is one form of the inversion theorem].

Comment: Thanks Kavi. But how can we prove that the c.f. $\varphi_Z$ of $Z=X+Y_\sigma$ is integrable? In other words, is the c.f. of any r.v. $X+Y_\sigma$ always integrable but not of $X$ itself?

Comment: @wuxj Chracteristic function of $X$ is bounded and that of $Y_{\sigma}$ is integrable. Hence the product is integrable.

Comment: Ah..I see. Thanks again Kavi, it's very kind of u :-)